# Create post with video throws "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action" in node.js FB API

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create post in FB group with video content using FB Graph API.
First issue - I send video (POST '<group_id>/videos') with option "published: false" but video is published (published: false works for photos)

Second issue - I got permission error when I'm trying to create post with video

```
const FB = require('fb');

media = await FB.api(`/${process.env.FB_GROUP_ID}/videos`, 'POST',
    {
        file_url: image.video_url,
        published: false,
        no_story: true,
    },
);

media1 = await FB.api(`/${process.env.FB_GROUP_ID}/photos`, 'POST',
          {
            url: image.image_url,
            published: false,
          },
        );

const { id } = await FB.api(`/${process.env.FB_GROUP_ID}/feed`, 'POST',
    { message: "Hello world!!!", attached_media: [{ media_fbid: media.id}, { media_fbid: media1.id}] },
);
```

Facebook debug information:

```
==== Query
  curl -i -X POST \
   "https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/276211843876262/feed?message=G%20g%20g%20g%20g%20g%20g%20g%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20r%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20r%20t%20t%20r%20r%20r%20r%20r%20r%20r&attached_media=%5B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22media_fbid%22%3A%20%221216999835778498%22%0A%20%20%7D%0A%5D&access_token=<access token sanitized>"
==== Access Token Info
  {
    "perms": [
      "user_photos",
      "user_videos",
      "user_posts",
      "publish_video",
      "catalog_management",
      "user_managed_groups",
      "groups_show_list",
      "pages_show_list",
      "publish_to_groups",
      "groups_access_member_info",
      "pages_read_engagement",
      "pages_manage_metadata",
      "pages_read_user_content",
      "pages_manage_posts",
      "pages_manage_engagement",
      "public_profile"
    ],
    "user_id": <user id>,
    "app_id": <app id>
  }
==== Parameters
- Query Parameters


  {}
- POST Parameters


  {
    "message": "G g g g g g g g t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t r t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t t r t t r r r r r r r",
    "attached_media": "[\n  {\n    \"media_fbid\": \"1216999835778498\"\n  }\n]"
  }
==== Response
  {
    "error": {
      "message": "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 10,
      "fbtrace_id": "AFiARMOWvZfM9GCSmTCMFcl"
    }
  }
==== Debug Information from Graph API Explorer
- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=POST&path=276211843876262%2Ffeed&version=v14.0&message=G%20g%20g%20g%20g%20g%20g%20g%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20r%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20t%20r%20t%20t%20r%20r%20r%20r%20r%20r%20r&attached_media=[%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22media_fbid%22%3A%20%221216999835778498%22%0A%20%20%7D%0A]
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting a video works different than posting images. You don't need the second call; simply modify your first call and remove the `no_story=true` and `published=false`, and add `description` (the `message` field on the feed) and `title` and it will work.

Comment: But if I want to create post with video and image I'll have the issue

Comment: What if someone wants to add a comment to that video post? This 1st call returns the `media_id` not the `post_id` so therefore this solution doesn't work. It posts a video but returns the `media_id`.